# 'GDTCORLibrary/Public/GDTCORTransport.h' file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I try to add Firebase to my project but on build stage this error appears.. where could the problem be? The strange thing is that the error appears in this particular project. When I tried to install Firebase to an empty project, there was no error.

[image]

Comment: if you are using pods, make sure you are opening workspace and not the project - that's one of the common reasons for this sort of error

Comment: In my case error appears in workspace

Comment: Firebase is a suite of different SDK's - Firestore, Storage, Realtime Database etc. So it's unclear from the question what you're trying to add. Additionally, those are odd looking #import statements if you're using Swift. Lastly, you should review the Firebase [List Of Available Pods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods) as those  are not on that list. Oh and *When I tried to install Firebase* is unclear... what steps did you use to *install Firebase* and what Firebase product was it?

Answer (score 10):

I just dealt this issue as well, and this is what I tried.

First, listening to the comments above and I made sure that I was opening the .xcworkspace

Second, I would suggest completely cleaning your project including clearing derived data. Additionally, you can try running `pod deintegrate` and then trying `pod install` fresh, reinstalling everything fresh.

I was able to get my project running after doing the latter of these two.

Comment: I ended up completely cleaning the project, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I used Matthew S.'s solution above to fix this problem. I'll just add that I originally had a "Workspace Integrity - Couldn't load project" issue when I opened XCode today which seems to have resulted from Pushing the project to my git repository without also pushing the associated pods. When I Pulled the project back down from the repository I got a slew of errors including the one mentioned in the subject of this post.
So to summarize:
I got this error: "Workspace Integrity - Couldn't load project"
To correct:

1. Pull project from git repository
2. Delete derived data
3. Clean and build project
4. pod deintegrate
5. pod install

Thanks Matthew for saving my morning. SEEEK.

Comment: pod deintegrate, then pod install worked for me